# How to handle multiple options with isMulti in react-select

Tags: reactjs, onchange, react-select

I am trying to make a select, where I can select different cities and filter out the ones not from the selected cities, my filter seem to work, but I can't select more than one city even tho I have set isMulti on Select I have also tried `isMulti={true}` but it does not work, I think it is my handler that doesn't work:

```
handleChange (selectedOptions) {
    selectedOptions.map(o => this.setState({by: o.value.value}))
      //var options = selectedOptions.value;
        /*var value = [];
        for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
          if (options[i].selected) {
            value.push(options[i].value);
          }
        }*/
        console.log(selectedOptions)
        
      }
```

the one commented out does not work either but it did work with html tag select.

this is my filter:

```
const filteredUsers = (usersGet.filter(item => {
        const checkHairColor = () => {
            if(Array.isArray(haircolor)) {
                return haircolor.length > 0 ? haircolor.includes(item.haircolor) : true;
            } else {
                return (haircolor === '') || (haircolor === item.haircolor);
            }
        }
        const checkCity = () => {
            if(Array.isArray(city)) {
                return city.length > 0 ? by.includes(item.city) : true;
            } else {
                return (city === '') || (city === item.city);
            }
        }
        const filter = (item.navn.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase()) ||
            item.navn.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase()) === '')
            && (item.age > minage || minage === '') 
            && (item.age < maxage || maxage === '')
            && checkHairColor()
            && checkCity();
        console.log(filter);
        return filter
        
        }))
```

But my filter I'm pretty sure works, but not for sure since I haven't gotten an array to send to the filter yet.

```
<Select 
    isMulti={true}
    hideSelectedOptions={false}
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    isSearchable={true}
    name="by"
    value={selectedOptions} 
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    options={byer}
   />
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fntxzp?file=index.js

Comment: May you provide any online example? (e.g. on stackblitz)

Comment: I'm not sure if  I did it correctly but here it is on stavkblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fntxzp?file=index.js

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uygysb?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

The problem with select was, that you did not updated the state correctly. If you are updating state in react, you should provide a brand new object. And update just the part you need to change.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uygysb?file=index.js

Comment: okay I can select multiple cities but it doesn't filter them so it seems like something still isn't working

Comment: Try to use debugger.

Comment: if I set selectedOptions to selectedOptions[0].value the filter works but not the multi select because selectedOptions comes uot as [Object],[Object] and not as ["name", "other Name"]